# NoReverseMatch at / django 1.8 form

Tags: python, django, forms

Im getting this error trying to load my index.html that has a form inside with a view call on the "action" tag.

```
NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'create' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/
Django Version: 1.8.3
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'create' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

This is my **urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^create_project/$', views.create, name='create'),
]
```

This is my **view.py**:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

def index(request):
   return render(request, 'menu/index.html')

def create(request):
   return render(request, 'menu/detail.html')
```

This is the **index.html**  part that shows the action tag that raises the error:

```
<form class="nobottommargin" id="template-contactform" name="template-contactform" action="{% url 'create' %}" method="post">
                                {% csrf_token %}

                                    <div class="col_half">
                                        <label for="name">Project Name <small>*</small></label>
                                        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="{{ current_name }}" class="sm-form-control required" />
                                    </div>
```

I dont know what im doing wrong, hope you can help me!

Comment: Are those urls included by another urls.py?

Comment: Agree w Daniel.  Specifically you may need to add a namespace to the % url bit if they are included that way at the higher level.

Comment: Hi, Daniel! thats the only file ( url.py) where i defined my urls. I wish to have another files for url in the future, but i prefer to keep it simple for now.

Comment: Note those url patterns should be in `urls.py`, not `url.py` (not sure if that's a typo in your question or a mistake in your code).

Comment: Sory, was just a typo, the file name is urls.py, thanks for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake was tha my urls have been included by another urls.py.

Thanks @Daniel Roseman

Answer (score 0):

I made a test with your data in the same Django version and work, check either because it must be something that is not there and has not imported.

Comment: You mean any **import from** statement missing? Check that i edit my question and i added to the code blocks with their respectives **import statements**

Comment: In __urls.py__ try `from yourapp import views`. If you can show the file structure of the project.

Comment: Javier i found my mistake discover by @DanielRoseman i have another urls.py defined before, i fell like a dumb, didnt notice...